# what is compileDebugJavaWithJavac task?

Tags: android, gradle

I found this task takes even half of total gradle execute task time. When I used `-x` to disable this task, everything seems still worked perfectly. So I want to know more about this task, and whether I should disable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`compileDebugJavaWithJavac` is for check whether you  follow the proper structure for Java code and compiler will check whether it makes sense or not .

If you disable it . It can create runtime error and your application may crash on various devices .

Thanks

Comment: thx! I've tried something like `i=0;`, which `i` is not defined. Although editor marked this error, but if I click `RUN`, this app still runs without check. It looks not necessary when I just modified some simple things.